# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5 error

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview and want to add one more item to list size which is 5. But when I `return list.size()+1;` It gives me error, saying `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 5`

Here is getItemCount

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return list.size();
    }
    else {return list.size() + 1;}
}
```

onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder.getItemViewType() == AD_TYPE) {
        if (mAd != null) {
            ((AdHolder) holder).bindView(mAd);
        } else if (mAds != null && mAds.isLoaded()) {
            NativeAd mAd = mAds.nextNativeAd();
            ((AdHolder) holder).bindView(mAd);
        } else {
            ((AdHolder) holder).bindView(null);
        }
    } else {

        int index = position;
        if (index == 3) {
            ++index;
        }
        listItem post = list.get(index);
        ((ListViewHolder)holder).bindView(post);
    }
}
```

Comment: but why your return size()+1 ..?

Comment: thats because you returning item count greater than the size of your dataset of recycler view. instead of doing "return list.size() + 1;"  try adding an item to your dataset.

Comment: There is another view which i want to put in the recyclerview. @NileshRathod

Comment: @GaneshSumb what you want to display in the extra view? a data from the dataset list or something extra which is not present in the dataset list?

Comment: No, its an ad. Check the link below, that's what i want to do. Link https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/blob/master/samples/android/scrollapp/app/src/main/java/com/fb/audiencenetwork/scrollapp/RecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: @GaneshSumb can you post your whole recycler view code here.

Comment: in your onBindviewholder IF condition replace holder.getItemViewType() to just getItemViewType(position)

Comment: https://github.com/sumbganesh/FB_Reycyler/blob/master/adapter.java here is the adapter.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: one more thing you want to display ads as last element or in between?

Comment: In between, on 3rd postion.

Comment: then in your bindview holder do this 
listItem post;
if (position > 3){
post  = list.get(position - 1);
} else {
post  = list.get(position);
}
 ((ListViewHolder)holder).bindView(post);

Comment: What is "post" in that?

Comment: its the object of type listItem. modify the else statement like the answer i provided below.

Comment: Sorry for that, I read it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your bindview holder change this

```
    int index = position;
    if (index == 3) {
        ++index;
    }
    listItem post = list.get(index);
    ((ListViewHolder)holder).bindView(post);
```

To This :

```
    listItem post; 
    if (position > 3){ 
        post = list.get(position - 1); 
    } else { 
        post = list.get(position); 
    } 
    ((ListViewHolder)holder).bindView(post);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. I want to ask one more thing, how can i do the same for recycled post?

Comment: I mean how can i add it on position%4 ==3?

Comment: you mean recycling adview and displlaying adview after every 4 items?

Comment: yes, I want ad on every 4th position starting from 3rd.

Comment: i have changed position == 4, but the it skips the ad on 3rd position. And if i do position % 4 ==3, then notthing happnes

Comment: The way you implemented ads recycler makes implementing that quite hectic.

Comment: instead of doint that you could just create 2 xml layouts for recycler view rows one with usual layout and other with usual layout + ads. and overload getItemviewtype method in recycler view and return ADVIEWTYPE if position % 4 == 0

Comment: It's not actually skipping the post on 3rd position, but it's skipping the post on 5th one.

Comment: and in your noteviewholder class create 2 constructor one with single parameter (View v) and second with 2 parameter (View v, int AdViewIndicator) and in OnCreateViewHolder  use if(viewType == ADVIEWTYPE) call the cosntructor with 2 parameter else call the constructor with single parameter

Comment: yeah.. in your current implementation everytime an adview appears the decrement counter increases

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return list.size();
    }
    else {
           // add here new data in your list like this than return size() of new list.
           list.add("data");
           return list.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give index out of bounds exception again since after  adding item you are again doing size of list + 1.

Comment: I am not able to understand, I am using 2 vietypes in the recyclerview and there is only one item of 2nd vietype. first view type is list with 5 items.